# Open a .ma file (ASCII) in Maya with Python?

Tags: python, ascii, maya, mel

I'm trying to open a maya scene `.ma` at the end of a Python script,

the path looks like that: `G:\ProjectPath\Scene.ma`.

But the only command I know for this is MEL command:

```
file -f -options "v=0; p=17; f=0" -ignoreVersion -typ "mayaAscii" -o 
"G:/ProjectPath/Scene.ma"; 
addRecentFile("G:/ProjectPath/Scene.ma", "mayaAscii");
```

Do someone know the way to do it in Python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a quick way you can do it via Python:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

# Windows path version
cmds.file('G:/ProjectPath/Scene.ma', o=True)

# Mac path version
cmds.file('/Users/mac/Desktop/Scene.ma', o=True)
```

Or try this version if you get messages like this `# Error: Unsaved changes`:

```
file_path = 'G:/ProjectPath/Scene.ma' 
cmds.file(new=True, force=True) 
cmds.file(file_path, open=True)
```

Comment: hello Andy..thanks for your answer, i'd try this for windows:
cmds.file( 'G:/ProjectPath/Scene.ma', o = True )
maya just given me this answer:
# Error: Unsaved changes.
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<maya console>", line 3, in <module>
# RuntimeError: Unsaved changes. # 
as i'm on a new scene, i'm not understand what appened...

Comment: it's just the exact path to the scene:
import maya.cmds as cmds
cmds.file( 'G:/ProjectPath/241/000A/001/LGT/SB_241_000A_001_LGT_005.ma', o = True )

Comment: Try to flush the opened new scene first: import maya.cmds as cmds

file_path = 'G:/ProjectPath/Scene.ma'

cmds.file( new=True, force=True ) 

cmds.file( file_path, open=True )

Comment: thank you very muxh Andy, i'll never find that without your help :)

Comment: Can I somehow use this without forcing a new scene with 'cmds.file(new=True, force=True)', so that the user get asked whether he wants to save his current open file or not?